# Decoding Video Data Per Pixel / Per Frame

Tags: html5-video, codec, raster

Are there some suggestions on decoding video data from a webcam in raw format, I would like the per pixel raster data frame per frame.

Comment: Is the html5-video tag intended? I mean, are you working in Javascript/do you want to do it in a browser?

Answer (score 0):

Use [libraw](http://www.libraw.org/) to load and decode RAW data. If the `html5-video` tag was intended and it means what I think, there is no way of doing this in a browser, besides [compiling it to Javascript](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki), if you feel really adventurous.